# How to access local variable inside package.preload in C++

Tags: c++, lua

The following code works fine and it prints `3` as expected.

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

void main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    //Script A
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function () local A = {}\n"
                     "A.num = 3\n"
                     "return A end");
    //Script B
    luaL_dostring(L, "local A = require 'A' print(A.num)");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

But I would like to get the value of `A.num` in C++.

I tried the following code but it doesn't print `A.num`.

```
lua_getglobal(L, "require");
lua_pushstring(L, "A");
if (lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0) != 0) 
{
    std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, 1) << '\n';
    lua_pop(L,1);
}
lua_getglobal(L, "num");
if (lua_type(L, -1) == LUA_TNUMBER)
    std::cout << "A.num : " << lua_tonumber(L, -1) << std::endl;
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

How can I properly get the value of `A.num` in `C++`?

Comment: `require'A'` returns a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require 'A'` returns a table.  That means you have to use `lua_getfield` rather than `lua_getglobal`.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <lua.hpp>

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function () local A = {}\n"
                     "A.num = 3\n"
                     "return A end");

    lua_getglobal(L, "require");
    lua_pushstring(L, "A");
    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, 1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "num");
    int isnum;
    double num = lua_tonumberx(L, -1, &isnum);
    if (isnum == 1) {
        std::cout << "A.num = " << num << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Field 'A.num' is not a number\n";
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1); // pop 'num'
    lua_pop(L, 1); // pop 'A'

    lua_close(L);
}
```

The two `lua_pop(L, 1)` can of course be combined into a single `lua_pop(L, 2)`

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Can I replace `double num = lua_tonumberx()` with `lua_pushnumber()` if I want to set `A.num`?

Comment: @ZackLee No, you replace everything after and including `lua_getfield(L, -1, "num");` with `lua_pushnumber(L, ???); lua_setfield(L, -2, "num"); lua_pop(L, 1);` (where ??? is the number you want to push) ([full example](https://hastebin.com/amorayuqon.cpp)).  It looks very much like you are again trying to establish some sort of communication between different scripts via variables in modules.  Don't do that.  Don't alter a module after it has been loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. It works now. I'd appreciate if you take a look at my other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434787/how-to-call-functions-inside-package-preload-in-c