# How to call functions inside package.preload in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to call `A:update(x)` and get a returned value `x + 3` in C++.

Here's my code:

```
#include <lua.hpp>

void main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function () local A = {}\n"
                     "function A:update(x) return x + 3 end \n"
                     "return A end");
    //call function
    lua_getglobal(L, "require");
    lua_pushstring(L, "A");
    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, 1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    int top = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "update");
    if (!lua_isfunction(L, -1))
    {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, 1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    lua_pushnumber(L, 5); //pass the argument 5
    if (lua_pcall(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
    {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, 1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    if (lua_gettop(L) - top)
    {
        if (lua_isnumber(L, -1))
        {
            std::cout << "RETURNED : " << lua_tonumber(L, -1) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1); // pop 'update'
    lua_pop(L, 1); // pop 'A'
    lua_close(L);
}
```

I expect it to print `RETURNED : 8` but I get the following error:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

How should I correct my code to work?

EDITED: It worked as soon as I change `A:update(x)` to `A.update(x)`. I thought they work identically except I can use `self` in a function that uses `:`. Could someone please explain to me why this happens?

Comment: You also have to call `A:update` with `self` as the first argument.  Currently you are calling `A:update` with `5` as the first argument (and miss the second argument entirely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation `A:update(x)` is syntactic sugar for `A.update(A,x)`.  That means you have to call the function `update` with two parameters.  You are lacking the first of the two parameters.

The first parameter `A` is already on the stack but is located “below” the `update` function.  Using `lua_pushvalue` we can push a copy of the table onto the stack.

Thus you have to call the function like this (omitting the error handling bits)

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, "update");
lua_pushvalue(L, -2); // push a copy of "A" onto the stack
lua_pushnumber(L, 5); //pass the argument 5
lua_pcall(L, 2, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now calling `A:update(x)` works without the problem. But is it not possible to call `update` function in C++ which works for both `A.update` and `A:update`?

Comment: @ZackLee By defining `function A:update(x)` in Lua you already specified that it can only be called as `A:update(x)` (which is equivalent `A.update(A,x)`).  The magic passing of the `self` argument only works inside the Lua interpreter with the `:` syntax.  In the C-API you have to explicitly pass the `self` argument.